# "getaddr info failed" Error When Attempting POST

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, urllib, httplib

I am using urllib and httplib to do an HTTPS POST to a web page, using a PEM cert file and key fileWhen I ran it I got the following error:
"I/O error (10109): getaddrinfo failed"

It is obvious I am getting the error trying to do the POST request.  How do I eliminate this error?

Comment: Can you manually resolve that hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used an incorrect syntax for the hostname and port number. Instead of:

```
HTTPSConnection("avaa2.example.mil:443", ...)
```

Try this:

```
HTTPSConnection("avaa2.example.mil", 443, ...)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection

Comment: Thank you, Rob, for your answer.  I made that change and that got rid of the error.  I am now getting a "400 Bad Request" error, but at least I am moving forward.  This error deals with what is in the request_URL and the annotation_string.